# Matlab CIC decimator output mirrored

Tags: matlab, decimation

I am trying to use the dsp.CICDecimatior function and comparing the output to a C code algorithm that I have. The CIC decimator is configured as decimation factor of 8 , 3 sections and differential delay equals 1.
below is the code used:

```
CIC1 = dsp.CICDecimator(8,1,3);
k=0;
step1_sig=zeros(1,128);
for i=1:16
    step1_sig(1,i)=CIC1(real(normalRx(1+k:8+k)'));
    k=k+8;
end
step1_sig'
```

The output looks mirrored as you can see in the figure below:

[image]

I am confident that the C code output is correct, because I have compared it to the following C++ :
https://github.com/EsonJohn/CIC-filter

Both produced the same output, so the issue have to be in my Matlab code.
In the traditional CIC decimator algorithm, the delay unit in the integrator is used in the feedback path, but in the MATLAB block it uses the unit delay in the feedforward path of the integrators:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/dsp.cicdecimator-system-object.html#d120e192907

[image]

Although the filter will be equivalent (same frequency response), the numerical output of the two implementations are a different (I guess it is the mirrored look that I mentioned above).

As it seems that the reason to the problem might be the way the CIC filter is implemented in MATLAB with the unit delay in the feedforward path of the integrator, the question now becomes:
**Is there a way of using the dsp.CICDecimator with the unit delay on the FEEDBACK path of the integrator?**

It should be like this:

[image]

Comment: The reason to NOT do this comes up in FPGA implementations where the delay is the path is consistent with synchronous logic. If there are any parasitic delays (such as what would occur in an FPGA) then such parastiic delays limit the maximum clock rate the CIC filter can run at.  I am not familiar with the dsp.CICDecimator specifically so can't answer your question but wanted to make you aware of that consideration.